# regex in Perl to capture the first n lines of each paragraph

Tags: regex, perl, line, capture, paragraph

I use `(\N+\n\N+\n\N+\n)` to capture the 3 first lines of a paragraph. What if I wanted to capture the 10 first lines, would I have to repeat this 10 times ? Is there a shorter way to do this ?

Take for example the following text file :

```
Lorem ipsum fuga quisquam occaecati officiis eaque pariatur.
Sunt in ea harum optio ducimus.
Iusto est sunt fugiat voluptas aliquid.
MY HEADER LINE
Dolores provident non sapiente rerum quasi voluptatem repudiandae debitis.

Dolores sint aut aut itaque dolorum nulla non vel.
Nobis nostrum necessitatibus est quidem.
Veniam est aperiam consequatur est.
MY HEADER LINE
Sunt ut dolorem est iure est adipisci porro.
Qui occaecati quisquam provident et dicta aperiam.
```

With Perl I can easily move the 4th line of each paragraph to the top of that paragraph :

```
$ cat test | perl -00 -pe 's/(\N+\n\N+\n\N+\n)(\N+\n)/$2$1/'
MY HEADER LINE
Lorem ipsum fuga quisquam occaecati officiis eaque pariatur.
Sunt in ea harum optio ducimus.
Iusto est sunt fugiat voluptas aliquid.
Dolores provident non sapiente rerum quasi voluptatem repudiandae debitis.

MY HEADER LINE
Dolores sint aut aut itaque dolorum nulla non vel.
Nobis nostrum necessitatibus est quidem.
Veniam est aperiam consequatur est.
Sunt ut dolorem est iure est adipisci porro.
Qui occaecati quisquam provident et dicta aperiam.
```

Is there a way to replace `(\N+\n\N+\n\N+\n)` with something shorter ?

Comment: Where did I say that I wanted to slurp the whole file ? ```-00``` treats each paragraph on its own, which is exactly what I want.

Comment: Was thinking of -0 which a lot of people mistakenly use instead of -0777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl's regexp engine supports the common `{N}` operator for selecting an exact number of repeats.  To do this, you need to group the parts you want to match again (and if you don't want to use the grouping parts later, prefix the group with `?:`)):

For example, grouping 10 lines together:

```
cat /tmp/test | perl -00 -pe 's/((?:\N+\n){10})(\N+\n)/$2$1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

The text can be read by paragraphs, split into array of lines, then you can manipulate lines according to your needs.

Following code snippet demonstrates this approach.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

{
        local $/ = "\n\n";

        while( <DATA> ) {
                my @lines = split("\n",$_);
                say join("\n",@lines[3,0..2,4..$#lines]) . "\n";
        }
}


__DATA__
Lorem ipsum fuga quisquam occaecati officiis eaque pariatur.
Sunt in ea harum optio ducimus.
Iusto est sunt fugiat voluptas aliquid.
MY HEADER LINE
Dolores provident non sapiente rerum quasi voluptatem repudiandae debitis.

Dolores sint aut aut itaque dolorum nulla non vel.
Nobis nostrum necessitatibus est quidem.
Veniam est aperiam consequatur est.
MY HEADER LINE
Sunt ut dolorem est iure est adipisci porro.
Qui occaecati quisquam provident et dicta aperiam.
```

Output

```
Y HEADER LINE
Lorem ipsum fuga quisquam occaecati officiis eaque pariatur.
Sunt in ea harum optio ducimus.
Iusto est sunt fugiat voluptas aliquid.
Dolores provident non sapiente rerum quasi voluptatem repudiandae debitis.

MY HEADER LINE
Dolores sint aut aut itaque dolorum nulla non vel.
Nobis nostrum necessitatibus est quidem.
Veniam est aperiam consequatur est.
Sunt ut dolorem est iure est adipisci porro.
Qui occaecati quisquam provident et dicta aperiam.
```

Reference:
[$/ - input record separator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar)